# ASP - Insert French Character in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, localization

I want to insert french characters in an Access database using ASP.
Can you please suggest me what can i do??

Many Thanks
Shaheen

Comment: Are you using htmlencode? How are you sanitizing data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is **half** the answer

If you know the ASCII code of the french character then you can use the **chr()** function e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TestTable ( Field1 ) VALUES ( Chr(133));
```

Here is a list of relevant ascii codes [french characters](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~vanemden/accents.html)

**[EDIT]** A rather more complete example below

```
Sub Test_ASCII()
    Dim strSQL As String, strName As String
    strName = "Andr" & Chr(133) 'Good French Name
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable ( Field1 ) VALUES ('" & strName & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

Query runs fine, but the French "e" is not displaying correctly. Probably my setup -- refer comment below

I only have access 2002, perhaps later version have support for UFT-8 or UNICODE?

Comment: Thing is, if shaheen is using html encode, Pádraig will become P&#225;draig. I find that most characters (cedillas etc, etc) display fine on my version of Access (2000)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do make sure to use `nvarchar()` (UTF-16) instead of `varchar()` (ASCII or something).
2. Make sure you don't apply any encoding except for escaping, on insertion. You just don't want to insert HTML values or something into the database.
3. It's very important that you don't do any decoding on retrieving. What goes in goes out (minus the escaping, of course).